# Can't view inserted images by Sharepoint Designer

Tags: html

When I insert a picture by `<img>` tag into a html code that I added into the site page and press F12, those images disappear.
But when I insert pictures with ribbon, I can see them.

Example1:

When I load site page, *href* value become empty ( "" ).

```
<a href="pictureBig">
  <img alt="Title" src="pictureSmall"  />
</a>
```

Example2:

When I normally just use `<img>` , they also become empty too.

```
<img alt="Title" src="pictureSmall"  />
```

After reload site page:

```
<img alt="Title" src=""  />
```

Why does it happen?
And I just want to know why this happens and how I can solve this. Thank you.

Comment: check your image path, check what's the path of the image when you are inserting through designer, and compare that with yours

Comment: Thank you for answering. It works now. The difference is ../. When I insert picture from SPD there is ../path but when I insert it by ribbon there is just path .

Comment: glad to know it worked :)

Comment: The images still can't be viewed. I think they display temporarily. I can't find why it happens. Please help